# How to handle empty string type data in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a very naive question but after referring to multiple articles, I am raising this concern. I have a column in the dataset where the column has `numeric/blank/null` values.
I have data like below:

```
fund_value

Null
123
-10
```

I wrote a method to handle it but it doesn't work and keeps on giving me the error:

```
def values(x):
    if x:
        if int(x) > 0:
            return 'Positive'
        elif int(x) < 0:
            return 'Negative'
    else:
        return 'Zero'

    df2 = pd.read_csv('/home/siddhesh/Downloads/s2s_results.csv')  # Assuming it as query results
    df2 = df2.astype(str)
    df2['fund_value'] = df2.fund_value.apply(values)
```

`Error`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/../Downloads/pyspark/src/sample/actual_dataset_testin.py", line 31, in <module>
    df2['fund_value'] = df2.fund_value.apply(values)
  File "/home/../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4357, in apply
    return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
  File "/home/../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1043, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "/home/../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py", line 1099, in apply_standard
    mapped = lib.map_infer(
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2859, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "/home/../Downloads/pyspark/src/sample/actual_dataset_testin.py", line 16, in values
    if int(x) > 0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nan'
```

I even tried `if x==""` or `if not x:` but nothing worked.

`Expected Output`:

```
fund_value  
Zero
Positive
Negative
```

Comment: Please share a sample input dataframe with expected output for better understanding.

Comment: I have added input and the expected output.

Comment: Is `Null` a string or a proper `Nan`?

Comment: a proper `Nan` value

Comment: How is the dataframe being constructed? [There are built in functions in pandas that can deal with missing data](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-missing-data-in-pandas/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering df to be:

```
In [1278]: df = pd.DataFrame({'fund_value': [np.nan, 123, '', 10]})

In [1279]: df
Out[1279]: 
  fund_value
0        NaN
1        123
2           
3         10
```

Use `numpy.select` with `pd.to_numeric`:

```
In [1246]: import numpy as np

In [1283]: df['fund_value'] = pd.to_numeric(df.fund_value, errors='coerce')

In [1247]: conds = [df.fund_value.gt(0), df.fund_value.lt(0)]
In [1250]: choices = ['Positive', 'Negative']

In [1261]: df['fund_value'] = np.select(conds, choices, default='Zero')

In [1288]: df
Out[1288]: 
  fund_value
0       Zero
1   Positive
2       Zero
3   Positive
```

Comment: Not sure this tackles the problem.. You are implicitly solving this by using `float` (which is great), but original question was trying to make a decision based on `int` cast .. that's what is the true problem here, less so the selection of the condition

Comment: @KingOtto I concentrated on sample input and expected output. I think that ways it's correct.

Comment: Sure, it is a great solution and fixes the problem! Just that next time someone is trying to do `int(np.nan)`, we go back to square 1

Comment: I want to replace the fund_value column itself. I don't want to create any flags column for it.

Comment: @whatsinthename Please check my answer now.

Comment: If you see my sample dataset, the first line in the dataset is not left blank intentionally, it is actually a blank value. My bad I didn't mention it in the post.

Comment: What do you want in case of `blank` value?

Comment: In case of blank, I want it as `Zero` only

Comment: @whatsinthename Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a problem of `NaN` support with `int`. That is something that does not work...

Your solution: Fill your "missing" values using `pd.fillna()`. Fill those values with something (e.g., with `0`), or remove them. Just read the values as `float`, which has native `NaN` support, then fill or remove those `NaN`

Background: The fact that you first cast the column to `str`, but then in your check function convert it back to `int`, which gives you a `NaN` error, looks like a workaround... Here is what causes the problem: Reading directly as `int` won't work, as `int` does not understand `NaN` --> see `Int` with capital **I**

Exampe: Assume you have a 'dirty int' input, that includes `NaN`, like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fund_value': [None, 123, 10]})
   fund_value
0         NaN
1       123.0
2        10.0
```

Pandas will do you the courtesy of converting this to `float`, given all values are numeric, and fills the "gaps" (`None` or `np.nan`) with `NaN`. You get something to screen, but in fact it is a column of `float`, not `int`.

**Option 1:** How to "convert" `NaN` values to '0' integer (for your case distinction between 'positive' or 'negative')

```
df.fillna(0).astype('int')
```

**Option 2:** Directly cast a column with `NaN` values to `Int`:

```
df.astype('Int32')
```

You can then work with either one of the datasets, which truly contain integers (option 1 with assuming all `NaN`==0, second one with true `<NA>`, not `floats`)

Comment: Can you help with the snippet? Little bit confusing

Comment: Type `int(np.nan)` into your console and see what happens... You *cannot ever* cast an `NaN` value into `int`. To fill NA values, see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `df2.astype(str)` turns everything into string, and when you apply `values(...)` to the contents of the column which are all string, the first `if`-check will only return you a `False` if it's an **empty** string which is not the case for `str(np.nan)`. Converting `np.nan` into string gives you a non-empty string `'nan'`.

`'nan'` will pass your first `if`-check, and then in the second `if`-check, it finds itself not convertible into an `int` and python returns you an error.

To take care of that,

```
x = df['fund_value'].replace('', np.nan).astype(float)

(x > 0).map({True: 'Positive'}).fillna( (x < 0).map({True: 'Negative'}) ).fillna('Zero')
```

Comment: Thank you again, Raymond :) Just one question, do I need to assign x to some variable?

Comment: `x` is a temporary variable to keep the float version of fund_value because I am going to use it 2 times in my second line of code. Btw, you may just assign the outcome of the second line back to df['fund_value'] or to the dataframe but a different column name.

Comment: Cool. Understood :)